# Why is midnight commander able to copy files so much faster than cp?

Tags: linux, storage, cp, midnight-commander

I discovered an interesting behavior of mc. When I copy files across devices (at least those that are smaller than free RAM) it seems that the copy is using writeback cache and is nearly instant (on one of my servers where storage is barely able to do 50MB/s it copied 6GB file with avg speed over 2GB/s in few seconds).

Then I checked /proc/meminfo and saw about 6GB in Writeback and notices that it's being slowly written to actual disk.

Then second interesting behavior (I am using btrfs), copying this large file within same filesystem (same block device) happens absolutely instantly (not even progress bar) and it seems that file is just cloned using btrfs's COW feature.

None of these super-fast copy mechanisms however work with ordinary cp command. When I run cp it's slowly copying files, being limited by the storage speed.

Why is mc so much faster in this? Until now I thought mc uses almost same mechanism for file copying as cp?

Comment: I am currently doing some tests, and all copy utilities I am testing take advantage of RAM buffering, including `cp` (testing on Debian 11). MC isn't faster

Comment: [Since coreutils 9.0 `--reflink=auto` is the default for GNU `cp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152639/108618). What implementation of `cp` is your question about?

Answer (score 2):

MC will use btrfs copy-on-write (see https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/1983) where possible.

You can do the same with `cp --reflink=auto`. Or `cp --reflink=always` if you want to error out when fast cloning isn't possible.